# Adding the actions to my yacc file using struct

Tags: c, compiler-construction, action, bison, yacc

I'm working on a compiler project from Pascal to Assembly, I've started with a simple yacc file solving just the simple addition and multiplication operations, but when I tried to add the action using the struct like an example that I found I get this problem:

```
projectf.y: In function ‘yyparse’:
projectf.y:65:10: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘=’ token
program = (struct program_t*) malloc(sizeof(struct program_t));
      ^
make: *** [projectf.tab.o] Error 1
```

this is my yacc file:

```
%{

#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define YYSTYPE char *


extern char *yytext;


typedef struct  {
  struct program_h_t *ph;
  struct main_t *mn;
}program_t;

typedef struct program_t *program;


typedef struct  {
    char *ident;
    struct ident_list_t *idl;
}program_h_t;

struct {
    struct var_declaration_part_t *vdp;
    struct operation_part_t *opp;
} main_t;

%}

%token SCOLON DOT COMMA COLON
%token PROGRAM LEFTP RIGHTP VAR IDENTIFIER
%token PBEGIN END EQUAL
%token NUMBER PLUS MINUS TIMES DIVIDE


%type <program> program
%type <ph> program_h
%type <mn> main
%type <id> ident
%type <idl> ident_list
%type <vdp> var_declaration_part
%type <opp> operation_part
%type <vdl> var_declaration_list
%type <vd> var_declaration
%type <op> operations
%type <ex> expression
%type <sexp> simple_expression


%union{
char *ident;
struct program_t *program;
struct program_h_t *ph;
operation_part_t *opp;
var_declaration_part_t *vdp;
ident_list_t *idl;
}
%%

program : program_h SCOLON main DOT
    {
    $$ = (struct program_t*) malloc(sizeof(struct program_t));
    }
    ;

program_h : PROGRAM ident
    {

    }
    | PROGRAM ident LEFTP ident_list RIGHTP
    ;

ident_list : ident_list COMMA ident
    | ident
    ;

main : var_declaration_part
    operation_part  
    ;

var_declaration_part : VAR var_declaration_list SCOLON var_declaration_part
    |
    ;

var_declaration_list :  var_declaration_list SCOLON var_declaration
        | var_declaration 
        ;

var_declaration : ident_list COLON ident
    ;

ident: IDENTIFIER
    ;

 operation_part : PBEGIN operations END
    ;

 operations : ident EQUAL expression SCOLON operations
    |
    ;

 expression :  simple_expression
         | simple_expression relop simple_expression
    ;

  simple_expression : term
          | simple_expression addop term
          ;

   term : factor
          | term mulop factor
           ;

   factor : NUMBER
           ;

   addop : PLUS
    |MINUS
    ;

 mulop : TIMES
    |DIVIDE
    ; 

 relop : EQUAL
    ;

 %%

 extern int line_no;


 int yyerror(s)
 char *s;
  {
           fprintf(stderr, "%s: at or before '%s', line %d\n", 
                    s, yytext, line_no);
 }


 main (void) {
    return yyparse();
     }
```

Any Help Can be appreciated it.

Comment: You have this typedef: `typedef struct program_t *program;` which makes the symbol  `program` a type. But you are also using `program` as a union member tag. That's probably not a good idea.

Comment: I've tried to change it but its not the problem :/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have both a `#define` for `YYSTYPE` and a `%union` declaration, which defines `YYSTYPE` as a union.  You cannot have both -- which do you want?  You probably want the union, so delete the define.

Another problem is this:

```
typedef struct  {
  struct program_h_t *ph;
  struct main_t *mn;
}program_t;
```

which defines an anonymous struct, and makes `program_t` an alias for it.  Then later in your program, you use `struct program_t`, which has never been defined.  Add in `program_t` between the `struct` and `{`.  The same problem occurs with `program_h_t` and `main_t` well.